# How-to prevent CSRF / XSRF in ASP.NET Core MVC App Web API Controller

Tags: c#, kendo-grid, asp.net-core-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui-mvc

Adding Anti Forgery to an Asp.Net Core MVC app is easily done by applying the **ValidateAntiForgeryToken** attribute to the action and using a `sp-antiforgery=true` in the form.

How can I secure a CRUD operation of Web API controller that uses individual authentication with the **Authorize** attribute and a Kendo MVC Grid in client side?

Comment: Hi Sean thanks for your valueable answer. I UPVOTED AND SET AS ANSWERED IT. Today I only found that link http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet/890/prevent-csrf-hacks-attacks-aspnet-webapi from 2013 and wanted to be sure that it still works with Asp.Net Core and Kendo UI for jQuery. THANKS AGAIN !

Comment: any time sir . I have given a reference to that link as well as kendo based specific implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a controller and inject `IAntiforgery` for getting the XsrfToken and then send this with request to validate.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class XsrfTokenController : Controller
{
    private readonly IAntiforgery _antiforgery;

    public XsrfTokenController(IAntiforgery antiforgery)
    {
        _antiforgery = antiforgery;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        var tokens = _antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(HttpContext);

        return new ObjectResult(new {
            token = tokens.RequestToken,
            tokenName = tokens.HeaderName
        });
    }
}
```

You can read more about it on [here](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2017/02/06/anti-forgery-tokens-and-asp-net-core-apis.aspx)

Comment: How can I add that to the Kendo UI for jQuery Grid in the client side? Thanks.

Comment: @Ahmar: How can I refresh the token after a successful login?

Answer (score 2):

> A CSRF attack can only happen when cookies are shared on the client.
>   By that I mean that the client has access to cookies from multiple
>   domains (such as a web browser storing cookies for each site you
>   visit). However, a web application API client typically only contacts
>   a single domain (that of your API). Any cross site attack cannot use
>   cookies within your API as the client is not shared (HTTP client in
>   web application is separate than HTTP client in the mobile browser -
>   or should be). Therefore your web application API should already be
>   safe against CSRF if the API is for your mobile application only.

There is a **generic guide** for implementing anti forgery token in webapi discussed here.

[Preventing CSRF Hacks in ASP.NET WebAPI](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet/890/prevent-csrf-hacks-attacks-aspnet-webapi)

***But since you are using kendo grid we have to look into something that work specifically for Kendo Grid.***

**1 :Using WEBAPI endpoint:**

**you can either do like using data :**
Send antiforgery token the regular way through the Data function of the Read transport

```
transport: {
    read: {
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            __RequestVerificationToken: $("input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]").val()
        }
    }
```

**Or using a parameter map :**

```
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

 <div id="grid"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                type: "json",
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "/Home/GetProducts",
                        type: "POST"
                    },
                    update: {
                        url: "/Home/UpdateProduct",
                        type: "POST"
                    },
                    parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                        options.__RequestVerificationToken = $("input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]").val();
                        return options;
                    }
                },
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "ID",
                        fields: {
                            ID: { type: "number", editable: false },
                            Name: { type: "string" }
                        }
                    }
                },
                pageSize: 10
            },
            height: 250,
            filterable: true,
            sortable: true,
            pageable: true,
            editable: "inline",
            columns: ["ID", "Name", {command: "edit"}]
        });
    });
</script>
```

your webapi controller

```
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult GetProducts()
        {
            return Json(products);
        }

        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public void UpdateProduct(Product updatedProduct)
        {
            var product = products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == updatedProduct.ID);
            UpdateModel(product);
        }
```

***2 : Using Ajax based calls***

we will make you of Data function in Datasource to send anti forgery token to CRUD ops

you will need to add this on page to generate the token

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

Then in a kendo grid Datasource configuration do this

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .Model(model=>model.Id(m=>m.PersonID))
                    .Read(read => read.Action("GetPersons","Home").Data("sendAntiForgery"))
                    .Update(up => up.Action("UpdatePerson", "Home").Data("sendAntiForgery"))
            )
```

Here is the javascript method that will send the token to CRUD ops

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sendAntiForgery() {
        return { "__RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val() }
    }
</script>
```

The controller on server side

```
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult GetPersons([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest dsRequest)
        {
            var result = persons.ToDataSourceResult(dsRequest);
            return Json(result);
        }

        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult UpdatePerson([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest dsRequest, Person person)
        {
            if (person != null && ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var toUpdate = persons.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PersonID == person.PersonID);
                TryUpdateModel(toUpdate);
            }


            return Json(ModelState.ToDataSourceResult());
        }
```

for more help look into these links on kendo documentation

http://www.telerik.com/forums/kendo-grid-antiforgerytoken#fPGvzDjUyEahRPNaTEo_TA
  http://www.telerik.com/forums/anti-forgery-tokens#VA3XA6lbT0WgeOwOQ3w_nQ

Comment: I get a 400 (Bad Request) with approach 1.) on the /api/Read endpoint. Can I email you ?